# "getMaster attempt 1 of 1 failed; no more retrying. com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe" when connecting

Tags: hadoop, exception, hbase

I'm trying to connect to HBase installed in the local system (using Hortonworks 1.1.1.16), by a small program in Java, which executes the next command:

```
HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(conf);
```

It is worth saying that there is no problem at all when connecting to HBase from the command line using the `hbase` command.

The content of the host file is the next one (where `example.com` contains the actual host name):

```
127.0.0.1 localhost example.com
```

HBase is configured to work in standalone mode:

```
hbase.cluster.distributed=false
```

When executing the program, the next exception is thrown:

```
13/05/13 15:18:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.5-1392090, built on 09/30/2012 17:52 GMT
13/05/13 15:18:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:host.name=localhost
13/05/13 15:18:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.7.0_19
13/05/13 15:18:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
13/05/13 15:18:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.19.x86_64/jre
13/05/13 15:18:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.class.path=[...]
13/05/13 15:18:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
13/05/13 15:18:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
13/05/13 15:18:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
13/05/13 15:18:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
13/05/13 15:18:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=amd64
13/05/13 15:18:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64
13/05/13 15:18:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=root
13/05/13 15:18:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/root
13/05/13 15:18:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/root/git/project
13/05/13 15:18:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=example.com:2181 sessionTimeout=60000 watcher=hconnection-0x678e4593
13/05/13 15:18:29 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this process is hconnection-0x678e4593
13/05/13 15:18:29 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
13/05/13 15:18:29 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
13/05/13 15:18:29 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x13e9d6851af0046, negotiated timeout = 40000
13/05/13 15:18:29 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: ClusterId is cccadf06-f6bf-492e-8a39-e8beac521ce6
13/05/13 15:18:29 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: getMaster attempt 1 of 1 failed; no more retrying.
com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ProtobufRpcClientEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcClientEngine.java:149)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.isMasterRunning(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.createMasterInterface(HConnectionManager.java:732)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.createMasterWithRetries(HConnectionManager.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getKeepAliveMasterProtocol(HConnectionManager.java:1724)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getKeepAliveMasterMonitor(HConnectionManager.java:1757)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.isMasterRunning(HConnectionManager.java:837)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(HBaseAdmin.java:2010)
    at TestHBase.main(TestHBase.java:37)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:94)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketOutputStream$Writer.performIO(SocketOutputStream.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.doIO(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:107)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.writeConnectionHeader(HBaseClient.java:896)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.setupIOstreams(HBaseClient.java:847)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.getConnection(HBaseClient.java:1414)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.call(HBaseClient.java:1299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ProtobufRpcClientEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcClientEngine.java:131)
    ... 8 more
13/05/13 15:18:29 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Closing zookeeper sessionid=0x13e9d6851af0046
13/05/13 15:18:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x13e9d6851af0046 closed
13/05/13 15:18:29 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.createMasterWithRetries(HConnectionManager.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getKeepAliveMasterProtocol(HConnectionManager.java:1724)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getKeepAliveMasterMonitor(HConnectionManager.java:1757)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.isMasterRunning(HConnectionManager.java:837)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(HBaseAdmin.java:2010)
    at TestHBase.main(TestHBase.java:37)
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ProtobufRpcClientEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcClientEngine.java:149)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.isMasterRunning(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.createMasterInterface(HConnectionManager.java:732)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.createMasterWithRetries(HConnectionManager.java:764)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:94)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketOutputStream$Writer.performIO(SocketOutputStream.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.doIO(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:107)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.writeConnectionHeader(HBaseClient.java:896)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.setupIOstreams(HBaseClient.java:847)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.getConnection(HBaseClient.java:1414)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.call(HBaseClient.java:1299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ProtobufRpcClientEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcClientEngine.java:131)
    ... 8 more
```

This trace provides some evidence of what may be actually happening. It seems that the connection to ZooKeeper is established, but something fails when tries to access the master.

Though I've spent hours trying to find a solution in Google, I haven't seen such an exception. Particularly, this exception varies from two things from most found elsewhere:

- Everybody seems to have the error `getMaster attempt 0 of 1 failed` rather than `getMaster attempt 1 of 1 failed`. I don't know whether this makes a point at all, but I find it somehow weird.
- I can't find other people getting the `Broken pipe` error.

By the way, the master is actually running, as far as I can see in the Hortonworks Management Console.

When looking at the most recent logs, this is the output:

```
2013-05-13 15:30:07,192 WARN org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: Incorrect header or version mismatch from 127.0.0.1:40788 got version 0 expected version 3
```

As it is a warning rather than an error, I don't know whether it has something to do with the actual problem. The port varies in each execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally we found the problem and solved it. It turned out to be a dependencies problem. We were using `hbase-0.95.0` and `hbase-client-0.95.0`. Using `hbase-0.94.7` or `hbase-0.94.9` seemed to work.

Yet, some problems occurred under certain circumstances even with that versions of the HBase library. Particularly, some problems arised when running it within an application server (JBoss AS7). In the end, all problems seems to be solved by removing the dependency `hbase-client-0.95.0`, and replacing it by `haboop-core-1.1.2` as some classes not contained in the hbase libraries were required.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend first check your HBase Master / RegionServer ports are really bound with `netstat -n -a`. I had situation when HBase Master IPC was bound to only external IP (this was Cloudera CDH) and it was not reachable through 127.0.0.1. It looks like most probable case for you - hbase shell should still work in this case.

Another possible reason could be previous cluster crash with some HDFS data corrupted. In this case HBase does not actually start waiting for HDFS to exit safe mode. But this looks like not your case. If it is, you can manually force HDFS to exit safe mode from console and then do `fsck` for Hadoop and similar procedure for HBase.